# Putting a into a cell and exporting to a word document

Tags: excel, vba

This is a theoretical question at the moment as I just wanted to gauge whether this was even possible before I attempted it.

So my question is; is there a way to paste a picture into a cell in excel so that it is the value of that cell. For example if the cell is referenced in my VBA code that would paste words or numbers into a word document, is there a way to do the same thing with a picture?

Maybe the file path of the picture could be used instead?

I am not too sure of how something like this would work any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Read up on [`Shape.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.copy) in Excel, and [`Range.Paste`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.paste) in Word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pictures and other shapes are not cell content in `Excel`. Instead they hover over the sheet in a special layer called drawing. They are anchored on the sheet. So, no, you cannot get a picture as the value of a cell as you can do it for cell content like numeric content (numbers or dates), formulas or text.

But of course you can check whether a [Shape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape) is anchored to a special cell by reading it's [Shape.TopLeftCell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.topleftcell) and/or [Shape.BottomRightCell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.bottomrightcell) property. Then [Shape.CopyPicture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.copypicture) can be used to transport that picture via clipboard.

If using a file path of the picture is an option, then this will be simpler since this is text only and so can be cell content and so can be transported such as other cell content too.